# Character behaves weid when adding Force to Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, rigid-bodies

i am currently working on a little project where i want to add my character dashing into the direction of the mouse position. For that i´ve wrote this code:

```
Vector3 worldPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        rb.AddForce( worldPos * DashSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
```

but if i execute that my charater dashes or lets say flys into the sky or drifts into the ground, can anybody explain the mistake i made i dont really understand the Problem. If i change the forcemode the character does float into the direction of the mouse on the right but not if the mouse is on the left side.

Comment: Is this code in your Update function? If it is does it help if you multiply ```worldPos * DashSpeed``` by ```Time.delataTime```

Comment: @MathewHD no it doesnt change anything if i hold the mouse button it either goes into the sky or the ground but not to the mouse pos. How would you add a dashing mechanic using a rigidbody ?